# Why is the word "complement" used in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Maybe this should have been on the English Exchange, but why do we use the word "complement" in set theory?  If I have:

$$(A \cup B)'$$

Why does "complement" mean everything but the union?  Is it because it is "all the things" that the original operation is not, thus it "completes" it?

I looked at the dictionary and wasn't sure.

Edit:  $(A \cup B)'$ was only an example so I could use the complement mark.  It was picked at random and was only meant to ask the question of what the word meant.  It was not specifically about a union.  I could have probably picked anything that allowed me to use the "tick mark" to indicate complement.  My MathJax is not good and cumbersome for me, so I only used the single example.

Comment: $A'$ would allow you to use the tick mark to indicate a complement, and it takes a lot less MathJax to write $A'$ than to write $(A \cup B)'.$ So it's still puzzling why you went to all the trouble to write something like $(A \cup B)'.$ But I suppose that's a moot point, since you already got the answer you needed.

Comment: " (A∪B)′ was only an example so I could use the complement mark."  A *FAR* simpler and more pertanent example would be $A'$.  Complement has nothing to do with unions so that is very misleading.  Complment is simply about sets. So just use a set.

Comment: "My MathJax is not good and cumbersome for me, so I only used the single example."  So why did you use a very hard example, instead of a very simple example.   And why did you use MathJax at all.  You don't need *ANY* MathJax to type A'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first non-mathy definition that [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complement) gives for "complement" is

> something that fills up, completes, or makes perfect

You may also note that the other definitions have a similar connotation.  Things complement each other if, when put together, they make up something that is complete.  For another mathematical example, consider complementary angles, which add up to a "perfect" right angle.

In set theory, a set and its complement form a universal set (i.e. if $X$ is the universe, then $A \cup A^c = X$).  Hence the two sets complement each other, in the sense that together, they make a whole.

Addendum:  the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/37642?rskey=pGF9o8&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) (this may require academic access) indicates that "complement" was first used in the mathematical sense in Billingsley's 1570 translation of Euclid's *Elements*.  At that time, it had been in English usage for at least 150 years (the earliest reference in the OED goes back to 1419, as far as I can tell, meaning something to the effect of "finishing or completing something").  The word originally comes from Latin: "complēmentum that which fills up or completes."

Comment: From Latin *complemens*, present participle of *complere*, where *com-* = "together" and *plere* ="to make full", so "that which together (with the given) makes full"

Comment: It is worth pointing out that a complement is not well defined without the extra knowledge of what "universe" it refers to. Set theoretical complements are actually fairly rare, since the actual complement of a set (i.e. $A^\prime=\{x; x\not\in A\}$) is never a set in ZF(C).

Answer (score 9):

Given how you talk about this, I suspect that part of your confusion is that you seem to think that the complement operator applies to some other operator (in your specific example, a union, but whatever other operator would end up there).  But, complement is an operator that is applied to *sets*, not to *operators*. So, I can just have $A'$ as the complement of set $A$.  And in the case of $(A \cup B)'$, the set to which you apply the complement operator *happens* to be the union of two sets.

So the complement is not, as you write, 'all the things that the original *operator* is not' (my emphasis) but rather 'all the things that the original *set* is not' (better put: 'all the things that are not in the original set'). Likewise, in your case, the complement does not 'complete' the operation of union, but simply 'completes' a set ... that again just happens to be a union of two sets.

Comment: Union was just an example.  Probably a poor one, but that was the intent (to be an example, not a poor one.)

Comment: @Johnny So why did you say "all the things that the original *operation* is not"? And why not just use $A'$ as an example?

Comment: "operation" could mean anything when I wrote it.  I had to put something there as an example, so I picked that.  It took me a while to format even that with MathJax, and I thought it was sufficient to get my question across.

Comment: @Johnny But why not put a *set* there? Why not just $A'$? You say you had to put *something* there ... I am still concerned that you think that the complement applies to whatever operator you would put there ...

Comment: Because I did not know what to put other than what I did or at least it seemed to be a good example in my mind.  I appreciate your answer.  It helps me greatly, but it was not quite the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @johnny OK, that's all good then ... sorry to pry! :)

Comment: I edited the question to clarify for everyone.

Answer (score 8):

"X complements Y" in colloquial English means basically "X has what Y lacks". This is exactly what the complement is in set theory, except that the complement of $A$ also has none of what $A$ has.

That said, my suspicion is that this term actually originates in mathematical French and was borrowed directly from mathematical French into mathematical English.

Answer (score 1):

The **complement** of set $A$ in set $X$, written $X\setminus A$, is "the other half" of $A$. The set $X\setminus A$ is what the set $A$ "needs" in order to "be whole" again. In this context, "being whole" means being all of $X$, so $A$ together  with $X\setminus A$ are whole.

More is true. There may be many sets that would make $A$ "whole" again, but $X\setminus A$ is the **smallest** of them all.

I pronounce the symbol "$X\setminus A$" as "$X$ without $A$", or "$X$ not $A$", or "$X$ punctured at $A$", or "the $X$-complement of $A$", or even "not $A$" when $X$ is clear from context.

The idea of *complement* is also very important in trigonometry (where $\pi/2-\theta$ is the $\pi/2$-complement of angle $\theta$), probability (where $1-p$ is the complement of probability $p$), and logic (where $\neg a$ is the complement of $a$ when both are elements of a [complemented distributive lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemented_lattice)).